# Performance difference between node-sass alone and Express middleware

Tags: node.js, express, sass

Let's have NodeJS Express web app:
Is there any performance hit when using node-sass for compilation manually (by watcher in WebStorm for eyample) or by making Express middleware, so it's get compiled on http request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example has a performance hit once while you're developing. The second example has the same performance hit every time an HTTP request occurs (or at least once if you use a CDN to cache assets). So, the 2nd is a bad idea IMO. Sass compilation should occur 1 time before deploying. You could even say the production environment need not even have these files.

Comment: Thanks. Sufficent answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could actually use the `node-sass-middleware`, it will spare you the overhead setup of watching in development or the building process. Just run the middleware only in development environment, otherwise omit it.

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"){
   app.use(/** You Sass Middleware */)
}
```

Easy setup + No performance worries